# How would you extend this search to cater for greedy search?

Tags: prolog

```
dfs([Node | OPEN], _ , Goal) :-  
Node==Goal, !,          
write('yes! goal reached.... ' - Goal), nl.         

dfs([Node | OPEN],CLOSED, Goal) :- 
  findall(                        Next,                 
  (
    arc(Node, Next),        Next
    not(member(Next, OPEN)),            not(member(Next, CLOSED))
      ), 
      NewNode               
     ), 

      append(NewNode, OPEN, NewOPEN),   
    write('OPEN = frontier of search...'), write(NewOPEN),nl,
    write('CLOSED = nodes already visited...'), write([Node | CLOSED]),nl,nl,
  dfs(NewOPEN, [Node | CLOSED], Goal).  % recurse with new data
```

arc(a,b).
arc(a,c).
arc(b,d).
arc(b,e).
arc(c,f).
arc(f,g).
arc(e,z).
arc(d,e).
arc(z,g).
arc(z,d).

Comment: Can we get some formatting please?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
dfs(Node, Goal) :- !.         

dfs(Node, Goal) :- 
    arc(Node, Next),
    score(Node, Next, S),
    not (score(Node, Next, S1), S1 > S), write(Next),
    dfs(Next, Goal).
```

Then you need to define a score for each arc, e.g. score(a, b, 3).

Comment: Thanks for the clue! And what if you want tp extend to a hill climbing search?

Comment: In that case we would need to agree on what you mean by hill climbing. The difference between greedy and hill climbing for this problem can be very subtle.